# Cannot add new security group rule in spinnaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, spinnaker

I've a spinnaker instance running in AWS EC2 Classic. I'm trying to setup the example bake and deploy pipeline in this page http://www.spinnaker.io/docs/bake-and-deploy-pipeline.

When I try to add a new security group rule, the group field is empty. I made sure the security groups cache is refreshed before trying to add the new security group rule.

Does spinnaker support EC2 Classic? Do I have to be on VPC to use spinnaker? If I deploy the spinnaker instance in VPC, can I deploy instances to EC2 classic?

Answer (score 0):

Spinnaker supports both EC2 Classic and VPC.

The group field is populated from your existing security groups and filtered to only show groups appropriate to the deployment target (e.g. only classic groups if you are deploying in classic)

If you hit the API endpoint for your spinnaker instance and list security groups, do you see the expected groups there?

http://your-spinnaker-api-host:port/securityGroups